# New to linux: permission Denied, How to read the output file after a cronjob is run?

Tags: python, linux, cron, permission-denied

I have a simply cron job that reads a hello.py file in virtual environment. The file basically says print " hello world". The cron job runs this file every minute and posts the output in a text file called " a.txt".

My cron job is as follows:

```
* * * * * /shared/index_scrapes/.venv/bin /shared/index_scrapes/hello.py >> /shared/index_scrapes/a.txt  2>&1
```

I can see the output file a.txt in my directory but when i try to read it by using the following command:

```
cat a.txt
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I have even tried making the file executable:

chmod u+x hello.py

Please help!

Comment: What user created the crontab entry? Also if you are acting as root to read that file, then you likely have the ability to `chown root /shared/index_scrapes/a.txt` but... that may make the file unwritable by cron on the next run depending on the answer to the first question.

Comment: making it executable doesn't help. run `ls -al` to find out who how the permissions and ownership of the file is and change it as needed. you can of course run `sudo cat` but that a bad practice.

Comment: -rwx------ 1 root root    51 Mar  9 11:48  hello.py is the permission and ownership for hello.py file @user1984

Comment: Sudo cat a.txt doesnt work either

Comment: @JNevill I ran the command and tried to then read a.txt, but its the same.

Comment: Run that `ls -al` on the file you are trying to read, not the python file.

Comment: -rwxr--r-- 1 root root  1701 Mar  9 15:32  a.txt @JNevill

Comment: Figured that would be the case. I suspect there is something happening with what looks like a symbolic link on that folder. I think this extends past the usual file permission issues that pop up. I'm out of my element at this point. If you don't get any traction from the other folks that pop in here, consider taking this over to unix.stackexchange.com and asking there.

Comment: @user1984 Do you know how to debug this issue?

Comment: @JNevill I have changed the permission for the file to 777, full access and yet the same issue arises

Answer (score 0):

I think you really cat your a.txt. Just the a.txt content is an error message!

You have a permission issue with /shared/index_scrapes/.venv/bin that generate the permission denied error text in a.txt.

Fix the permission to /shared/index_scrapes/.venv/bin and it will do the job